# template not always rendering

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I've got a template that is being rendered correctly 9 times out of 10, but sometimes it is not, it just doesn's show up. There don't seem to be any error messages in the log, how should I go about debugging this? What could it be?

The main template (application.hbs) is build up as:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12 page_top_header base_color_background"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid header_container">
    <!-- Logo -->

    <!-- Menu -->

  </div>
</div>
<!-- Line Divider -->
<div class="row-fluid ">
  <div class="span12 page_top_header line-divider"></div>
</div>

</div>
{{outlet}}
{{render footer}}
```

The footer itself is mainly text, with a few props in the controller, nothing fancy. I've got the following logging:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
  LOG_BINDINGS: true,

  currentUser: null
});
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

### EDIT

ApplicationController and Router:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['currentUser'],

  init: function() {
    'use strict';

    this._super();

    $.pnotify.defaults.history = false;
    $.pnotify.defaults.delay = 5000;
  },

  logout: function() {
    'use strict';

    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/users/sign_out.json',
      type: 'DELETE',
      success: function(){
        $.pnotify({type: 'success', title: 'Afmelden', text: 'U ben succesvol afgemeld.'});

        self.set('controllers.currentUser.content', null);
        self.transitionToRoute('index');
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  }
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    var attributes = $('meta[name="current-user"]').attr('content');
    if (attributes) {
      var user = App.User.create().setProperties(JSON.parse(attributes));
      this.controllerFor('currentUser').set('content', user);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: how do the `ApplicationController` and `ApplicationRoute` look like that drive the template?

Comment: @intuitivepixel Added in the post, also nothing in particular I believe. It seems to happen more often when nobody is logged in.

Comment: You have an extra closing div (`</div>`) in your application template.  Also it would be helpful if you showed which template is not rendering and how you get to it.

Comment: I indeed had a additional closing div, fixed that. I also had a explicit Ember.View that only contained a templateName attr referencing the footer.handlebars. I removed that view, and since it's running fine.